# List Comprehension Appending Index with Number Range on List of Lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

I am looking for a list comprehension in adding a range of numbers based on index position in a list of lists while keeping the second index alone.

```
search_keys =  [('1', 'B'), ('1', 'K'), ('1', 'Y')]
```

Desired Result:

```
new_search_keys = [('11', 'B'), ('12', 'B'), ('13', 'B'), ('14', 'B'), ('15', 'B')...
                  ...('11', 'K'), ('12', 'K'), ('13', 'K'), ('14', 'K'), ('15', 'K')...
                  ...('11', 'Y'), ('12', 'Y'), ('13', 'Y'), ('14', 'Y'), ('15', 'Y')...]
```

My attempt brings a TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable:

```
new_search_keys = [search_keys[i][0] + list(range[1,9]) for i in range(len(search_keys))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:-

```
new_search_keys = [(search_keys[i][0] +str(j), search_keys[i][1]) for i in range(len(search_keys)) for j in range(1,9)]
```

Output:-

```
[('11', 'B'), ('12', 'B'), ('13', 'B'), ('14', 'B'), ('15', 'B'), ('16', 'B'), ('17', 'B'), ('18', 'B'), ('11', 'K'), ('12', 'K'), ('13', 'K'), ('14', 'K'), ('15', 'K'), ('16', 'K'), ('17', 'K'), ('18', 'K'), ('11', 'Y'), ('12', 'Y'), ('13', 'Y'), ('14', 'Y'), ('15', 'Y'), ('16', 'Y'), ('17', 'Y'), ('18', 'Y')]
```